# Query MongoDB 'ObjectId' in C# Linq Driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq

I am attempting to retrieve a document by the default MongoDB Object ID.

Based on previous answers that I have found, I am currently using the code below

```cs
var collection = _databaseContext.getCollection();
var recordIDFilter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("id", ObjectId.Parse(recordId));
var query = collection.Find<BsonDocument>(recordIDFilter);

var result = query.ToList();
```

Having logged all the variables, I am confident that the query is being built correctly.
However, when running the code against a MongoDB database, the result is being returned as null, despite the fact that I am providing an Object Id I know is in the Database

Is there anything that is obviously missing from the code snippet, or is there any troubleshooting that could be advised to identify why the code is not returning a result

Answer (score 0):

There is much easier way of getting objects from mongo, by using LINQ.
You need to do only one thing and it is just to convert collection to Queryable.

Example (based on your code):

```
var collection = _databaseContext.getCollection();
var result = collection.AsQueryable().FirstOfDefault(c => c.id == recordId);
```

Comment: When using that function, I get the following error message: 

`'BsonDocument' does not contain a definition for 'id' and no accessible extension method 'id' accepting a first argument of type 'BsonDocument' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`.

I'm using both `System.Linq` and `MongoDB.Driver.Linq`, is there another assembly I should be adding?

Comment: Hello! Are you mapping yours mongodb's entity to some class? :)

Comment: Hi! I have it mapped to a class for the domain and response, using BsonId attribute, but it only gets allocated in that way after data has been retrieved from the database

Comment: Ok. GetCollection() is of generic type: `IMongoCollection<TDocument> GetCollection<TDocument>(
 string name,
 MongoCollectionSettings settings = null
)`, as TDocument use your model with BsonAttribute :)